# How can I add column descriptions in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I'm currently in the process of building an SSIS ETL from an excel sheet. My manager has asked if I can include notes above the column titles as descriptions in the table. It looks something like this currently:

```
| [Seeded from NAV, unless forecast] | [maybe used in input for lkup. 8Max] | [Seeded from NAV, unless forecast] |
| EntCode | EntShortName | EntName           |
|---------|--------------|-------------------|
| Ent1    | Entity1      | Entity Number 1   |
| Ent2    | Entity2      | Entity Number 2   |
```

Everything from the EntCode line down is already pulled into the database, but is there a transform that'll pull the line above the titles into the description?

I wondered if I should set up a second excel source for the notes row and then use sp_updateextendedproperty but I'm not sure how to run an SQL script in the data flow step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple different ways to approach this.

Define your Excel connection manager twice. One will have the parameter of data starts on row 2 and that's what's going to be used in the data flow itself. Otherwise, you have to try and filter out that "weird" first row and the data flow itself will set data types based on the first 8 rows and that can mess everything up.

The second Excel connection manager would not have that set and you'll want to only consider the first row from there. Whether you try and do that in an actual Data Flow or some custom scripting or possibly a query is really going to depend on your competency and possibly the ability to have software installed (ACE drivers).

If a data flow is used, then you're looking at either a series of `OLE DB Command` one for each column as I don't *think* you can have multiple exec calls in a singe one. And it might not even work, OLE DB Command is a bit fiddly.

Otherwise, a `Script Component` instead of OLE DB Command, acting as a transformation and then you're just going to be writing C# to run the stored procedure for each column.

Were it me, I'd probably just go with a Script Task and install the ACE drivers or an old (free) version of [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) to the GAC and write the code to pull the first line of a worksheet and for each column of data, issue the `sp_updateextendedproperty` call.

Final way and I'd have to dig deep on the specifics but you can do it all in the control flow with the existing Tasks (no Script).

This would look like a Foreach Enumerator set to the ~ADO schema rowset~ something type and then you can enumerate through the columns of an Excel spreadsheet (assuming you set the extended properties to have a header of True). Shove the current column "name" into a variable even though it will contain the actual value you want.

At this point, I'm not sure because the stored procedure call needs to specify the table and column. I guess you could have an Execute SQL Task to query sys.columns for that table and based on an SSIS variable of a counter id, you can see what the column name is and then build out the appropriate call. A lot more steps here but I think it should work.

Comment: Hi, thanks I'll try this later. I was thinking around these lines, but it's good to have the methodology confirmed. I'll see if OLE DB behaves because I can't write "hello world!" in C#! :-)